# Node Nested HTTPS Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, httprequest

I am writing a Node Script to make multiple HTTPS request. The second call relies on the first call for uri params. I am able to retrieve data from the first call by using node request module. But stuck with the second call as I need to pass in uri param from the first call to the second url. Goal is to fetch all servers on the first call and fetch server properties on the second call till I loop through all the users.

I tried using Promise too but get stuck when I have to make the second call.

**Please provide working example.**

**Here is my code:**

```
/**********************************************************************
DEPENDCIES MODULES
***********************************************************************/
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var app = express(); 

/*************************************************************************
SOLUTION
*************************************************************************/
var username = '123',
    password = 'password*',
    role = 'Read-Only',
    url_host = 'https://link.com:1000' 

var url1 = url_host + '/type/PropertySetClasses/SystemObject/Servers/?username=' + username +  '&password=' + password + '&role=' + role;
var url2 = url_host + server_id[i] + '?username=' + username +  '&password=' + password + '&role=' + role;


var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString("base64");

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
}

request.get(
    {
        url: url1,
        headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    },
    // FETCH ALL SERVERS
    function (error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var servers = JSON.parse(body);
        servers = servers.PropertySetClassChildrenResponse.PropertySetClassChildren.PropertySetInstances.Elements;

        // console.log(JSON.stringify(servers));

        var server_id = [];
        var result = servers.map(function(server) {
            servers = server.uri;
            server_id.push(servers);
        });
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(server_id));
        }
    }

); // END REQUEST
```

Comment: var url2 = url_host + id_array[i] ... is this "id_array" refers to "server_id"? and you want to fetch and process "server_id" s asynchronously am I right?

Comment: Sorry. Yes it refers to server_id. Just edited the code.

Comment: And yes, asynchronously. Currently, I just want to accomplish fetching server properties. That is my end goal.

Comment: I only see one request in here (the initial `request.get()` call).  Where are you making requests against the other servers?  Also, are you intentionally overwriting your servers variable several times, including in the `.map()` function?

Comment: @paul I am not yet as I am not sure what steps to take further. This is where I am stuck. I don't know if I need to make a nested request or another get request.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your confusion.  If you need to make another request against each of the servers, make one.  There no such thing as a "nested request".  Either you're making a request or you're not.

Comment: @paul yes I am doing that intentionally. I am assuming not the best way to write the code.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday?

Comment: as a side note, putting the username and password into the URL is absolutely awful.  There's no good reason to do it and a lot of good reasons not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's hard to make sure this works right in your environment, but if I were doing this I'd probably use the `async` library.  Once you have the (I'm assuming Array) of `servers`, you can use async to send out multiple requests in parallel or in series, depending on what you're trying to get:

```
function getServerInfo(server, callback){
  var url = // build the URL to the current server, it wasn't clear to me how you were doing that either

  var options = {
        url: url,
        headers: {
        'Authorization': auth,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    request.get(options, function(e,res,body){
      if(e) return callback(e);
      var json = JSON.parse(body); // probably do a try..catch just in case
      return callback(null, json);
    }

}

async.map(servers, getServerInfo, function (err, results){
  // results here is now an array of the data called back on each getServerInfo call
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var async = require('async');
// npm install async

var app = express();

var username = '123',
    password = 'password*',
    role = 'Read-Only',
    url_host = 'https://link.com:1000' 

if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
}


function doRequest(params, callback)
{
    request.get(params, function(error, response, body)
    {
        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200)
        {
            callback({error: error, statusCode: response.statusCode});
            return; // [!] break
        }

        callback(null, response, body);
        // export
    });

}

var url = url_host + '/type/PropertySetClasses/SystemObject/Servers/?username=' + username +  '&password=' + password + '&role=' + role;
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString("base64");

var requestParams = {
    url: url,
    headers: {
    'Authorization': auth,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

// FETCH SERVER LIST
doRequest(requestParams, function(err, response, body)
{
    if (err) {
        throw new Error('unable to fetch server data: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    }

    var servers = JSON.parse(body);
        servers = servers.PropertySetClassChildrenResponse.PropertySetClassChildren.PropertySetInstances.Elements;

    var server_ids = [];
    var result = servers.map(function(server)
    {
        // servers = server.uri; // ??? why

        /**
         * merge all "server ids" here somehow
         */
        server_ids.push(server.uri);
    });

    var tasks = [];
    // async work chain

    var results = {};
    // response obj.

    server_ids.forEach(function(server_id)
    {
        tasks.push(function(next)
        {
            var params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(requestParams));
            // clone | extend main params.

            params.url = url_host + server_id + '?username=' + username 
                + '&password=' + password + '&role=' + role;

            doRequest(params, function(err, response, body)
            {
                if (!err)
                {
                    results[server_id] = {response: response, body: body};
                    // || arguments
                }
                else {
                    next([server_id, err]);
                }
            });
        });
    });

    // https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback
    async.waterfall(tasks, function(err)
    {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('the server with Id: ' + err[0] + ' failed with error: ' + JSON.stringify(err[1]));
        }

        console.log(results);
        // all done!
    });

    /**
    // https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel
    async.parallel(tasks, function(err)
    {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('the server with Id: ' + err[0] + ' failed with error: ' + JSON.stringify(err[1]));
        }

        console.log(results);
        // all done!
    });
    /**/

    /**
    // https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel
    async.parallelLimit(tasks, 10, function(err)
    {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error('the server with Id: ' + err[0] + ' failed with error: ' + JSON.stringify(err[1]));
        }

        console.log(results);
        // all done!
    });
    /**/
});
```

I can't test it but hope you get the idea. Just create a task list and run it with "async".